# Hashtable style collection creation using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, collections, hashtable, addition

In JavaScript I want to create a collection in following way -

Start with an empty collection with `var c = [];`

Then I want to add item in it; after addition it will look like

```
{ 'buttonSubmit': function() { /* do some work */ } },
{ 'buttonCancel': function() { /* do some work */ } }
```

I must add item one by one using loop and records are not json string. I know the push method but problem is it creates indexed array which I don't want to use because I want to retrieve the value from the collection using `c['buttonSubmit']` or `d.buttonSubmit`. I want to avoid looping and compare key name.

Please help me with some simple code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you started `c` as an array, which uses numerical indexes to refer to what's inside it. What you want is to have `c` as an object, which uses keys to refer to the data inside it.

```
var c = {};
c.buttonSubmit = function(){...};
c.buttonCancel = function(){...};

//similarly
var c = {
  buttonSubmit : function(){...},
  buttonCancel : function(){...}
}

//using them via dot notation
c.buttonSubmit();
c.buttonCancel();

//using them via bracket notation
c.['buttonSubmit']();
c.['buttonCancel']();
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try your solution.

Comment: I combined your answer with this code and completed my requirement thanks a lot.

var data = {
    'PropertyA': 1,
    'PropertyB': 2,
    'PropertyC': 3
};

data["PropertyD"] = 4;

// dialog box with 4 in it
alert(data.PropertyD);
alert(data["PropertyD"]);